# How to mock Angular modules before injecting?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection

I have the following dependencies in my application:

```
angular.module 'MyApplication.NetworkingModule', ['ngResource']
       .value  'NetworkingValues'

angular.module  'MyApplication.MyModule', []
       .factory 'MySpecificResource', ['NetworkingValues',   ...]
       .factory 'MyService',          ['MySpecificResource', ...]
```

So `MySpecificResource` depends on `NetworkingValues`.

The thing is I'd like to mock some of these values before using them in resources in tests.

Doing this:

```
  beforeEach module 'MyApplication.NetworkingModule'
  beforeEach module 'MyApplication.MyModule'
```

causes that `factory` is invoked immediately and I don't have a chance to replace some of `NetworkingValues`.

```
beforeEach inject (@MyService, @NetworkingValues) ->
```

`MyService` depends on `MySpecificResource`, which depends on `NetworkingValues` that I want to stub before tests.

What are the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
Have you tried something along these lines?

 var mockedValues;
 beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value('NetworkingValues',mockedValues);
 }));

 beforeEach(inject(function(_NetworkingValues_) {

    mockedValues = {....};

 }));
```

The $provide will supply your mockedValues instead of the actual NetworkingValues.

Answer (score 0):

So my final solution was to provide constant and inject it together with `module` function:

```
beforeEach module "MyApplication.NetworkingModule", ($provide) ->
  $provide.constant 'NetworkingValues', endpointGet: 'my-endpoint/:id'
```